# Overall Percentage calculation in spark with scala

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Spark with scala**

My Product data frame looks like

```
Product            countnum
+----------------+----------------+
|Resistor        |               2|
|Capacitor       |               2|
|Inductor        |               3|
+----------------+----------------+
```

i am trying to get overall percentage like below:-

```
Product         countnum            Overall Profit
+----------------+----------------+--+----------------+
|Resistor        |               2|28%-- 2/7*100(Here 7 is total countnum)
|Capacitor       |               2|28%-- 2/7*100(Here 7 is total countnum)
|Inductor        |               3|42.85%-- 3/7*100(Here 7 is total countnum)

+----------------+----------------+--+----------------+
```

Code:

```
val df = newdf.select("countnum"/(sum("countnum") as("percentage") ,"product","countnum",)
```

but it is giving error as `"cannot resolve overloaded method 'select'`

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **window function** to get **`sum(countnum)`** and then **`divide`**

**`Example:`**

**`Approach1: Using window functions`**

```
df.show()
//+---------+--------+
//|  product|countnum|
//+---------+--------+
//| Resistor|       2|
//|capacitor|       2|
//| inductor|       3|
//+---------+--------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val w=Window.orderBy("countnum").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn("overallprofit",col("countnum")/sum(col("countnum")).over(w)*100).show()
//+---------+--------+------------------+
//|  product|countnum|     overallprofit|
//+---------+--------+------------------+
//| Resistor|       2| 28.57142857142857|
//|capacitor|       2| 28.57142857142857|
//| inductor|       3|42.857142857142854|
//+---------+--------+------------------+
```

**`Approach2: Without using window functions`**

```
val df1=df.select(sum("countnum").alias("overall_sum"))
df.crossJoin(df1).withColumn("overallprofit",col("countnum")/col("overall_sum")*100).
drop("overall_sum").
show()
//+---------+--------+------------------+
//|  product|countnum|     overallprofit|
//+---------+--------+------------------+
//| Resistor|       2| 28.57142857142857|
//|capacitor|       2| 28.57142857142857|
//| inductor|       3|42.857142857142854|
//+---------+--------+------------------+

//rounding
df.crossJoin(df1).withColumn("overallprofit",concat(round(col("countnum")/col("overall_sum")*100,2),lit("%"))).drop("overall_sum").show()
//+---------+--------+-------------+
//|  product|countnum|overallprofit|
//+---------+--------+-------------+
//| Resistor|       2|       28.57%|
//|capacitor|       2|       28.57%|
//| inductor|       3|       42.86%|
//+---------+--------+-------------+

//cast to decimal with one precision
df.crossJoin(df1).
withColumn("overallprofit",concat((col("countnum")/col("overall_sum")*100).cast("decimal(10,1)"),lit("%"))).
drop("overall_sum").
show()
//+---------+--------+-------------+
//|  product|countnum|overallprofit|
//+---------+--------+-------------+
//| Resistor|       2|        28.6%|
//|capacitor|       2|        28.6%|
//| inductor|       3|        42.9%|
//+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank You Sir....... can we round value to 0 if it is . 006, i mean if double 0 after point.

Comment: @RashmiGhosh, Try with **casting to decimal** with precision(1), Check mmy updated answer `//cast to decimal with one precision` section!

Answer (score 1):

The below code may help you.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Resistor", 2), ("Capacitor",2), ("Inductor", 3))).toDF("Product", "countnum")
df.show()
/*
+---------+--------+                                                            
|  Product|countnum|
+---------+--------+
| Resistor|       2|
|Capacitor|       2|
| Inductor|       3|
+---------+--------+
*/

df.groupBy("Product").agg(sum("countnum").alias("sum")).withColumn("fraction", round(((col("sum") /  sum("sum").over()) *100),2)).show()
/*
+---------+---+--------+                                                        
|  Product|sum|fraction|
+---------+---+--------+
| Inductor|  3|   42.86|
| Resistor|  2|   28.57|
|Capacitor|  2|   28.57|
+---------+---+--------+

*/
```